# Java Hello World App Does Nothing on Launch When Image Displayed

Tags: java, netbeans, java-6

I've got a small "hello world" app I've created, using `JFrame`/`JPanel`, and it works flawlessly inside my IDE (Netbeans).  I tested it with just drawing a string to the screen using `Graphics.drawString()`, and it worked perfectly both in the browser, and in the built .Jar file.

I decided to add in an image just to test it out (I'm new to Java), and the App continued to function inside the IDE, but the built .Jar file doesn't launch anything, or give an error or anything.

Here are the 2 class files:

Boxy_Main.java:

```
package boxy;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;

public class Boxy_Main extends JFrame {

    public static Boxy_Main main;

    public Boxy_Main() {
        add(new Board());
        setTitle("Boxy");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(467, 700);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main = new Boxy_Main();
    }
}
```

Board.java:

```
package boxy;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel {

    public Graphics2D g2d;
    public Graphics g;
    public Image hello_image;

    public Board() {

        this.set_properties();

    }

    public void set_properties() {

        this.hello_image = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../images/LKRZV.jpg")).getImage();


    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        this.g = g;
        this.g2d = (Graphics2D) g;


        this.g2d.drawImage(this.hello_image, null, this);

        this.g.drawString("hello", 100, 80);
        this.g.drawString("world", 100, 94);


    }
}
```

If I comment out

```
this.hello_image = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../images/LKRZV.jpg")).getImage();
```

and

```
this.g2d.drawImage(this.hello_image, null, this);
```

it continues to work perfectly.

I've tried to figure this out myself, I can't find anything via google or stack overflow. It is a difficult search phrase to craft.

Anyone have any ideas why this would run in NetBeans, but not as a standalone .Jar?

Comment: Loading ressources from a Jar file is rather tricky. Try to comment out only the drawImage(...

Comment: @kw4nta I forgot to specify that was the first thing I tried. The problem still existed so it is definitely having to do with the image loading, not the drawing. However, mrranstrom has pointed out what appears to be my mistake, I used a relative path that doesn't apply once the App is a .jar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is in this line

```
this.hello_image = new ImageIcon(Board.class.getResource("../images/LKRZV.jpg")).getImage();
```

The "../images.LKRZV.jpg" path is correct when you're running in NetBeans, but it isn't correct when you run your JAR.  Make sure you provide a provide a path that is correct relative to your jar file's location.  If you change that path to the absolute path of your image, your program should work correctly.  It would probably be better to pack the image in with the jar.

Comment: Wow, thank you. I feel like an idiot for not having thought of this. Now I feel like I've polluted S.O. unnecessarily...